# Assign a specific user to a signature block in Docusign

Tags: c#, docusignapi

I am using the docusign-csharp-client to enable electronic signatures in our application.

I have a PDF that requires a customer signature as well as a sales person's signature.

We use the C# client to to perform the embedded signature process for the customer and the salesperson. With the C# client we create the envelope, upload the PDF to be signed, and also add the signers and their info to the envelope. Everything seems to be working except I can't figure out how to get signature box 1 to show up for the customer to sign and signature box 2 to show up for the salesperson to sign.

The signature boxes have been added to the PDF. But when each of the two parties get into Docusign no signature box appears for either of them.

How do I link the customer to SignatureBox1 and the salesperson to SignatureBox2?

Below is the class I created for making the call to Docusign. The method `SendContractToDocusign()` is what kicks off the process.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Core.Domain.Models;
using Core.Interfaces;
using DocuSign.eSign.Api;
using DocuSign.eSign.Client;
using DocuSign.eSign.Model;
using Configuration = DocuSign.eSign.Client.Configuration;

namespace Infrastructure.Econtract
{
    public class DocuSignContract : IDigitalContract
    {
        private readonly IConfigurationSettings _configurationSettings;

        public DocuSignContract(IConfigurationSettings configurationSettings)
        {
            _configurationSettings = configurationSettings;
            var username = configurationSettings.DocusignUserName;
            var password = configurationSettings.DocusignPassword;
            var integratorKey = configurationSettings.DocusignIntegratorKey;
            var clientRestUrl = configurationSettings.DocusignClientRestUrl;

            var apiClient = new ApiClient(clientRestUrl);
            Configuration.Default.ApiClient = apiClient;

            if (!Configuration.Default.DefaultHeader.ContainsKey("X-DocuSign-Authentication"))
            {
                // configure 'X-DocuSign-Authentication' header
                string authHeader = "{\"Username\":\"" + username + "\", \"Password\":\"" + password + "\", \"IntegratorKey\":\"" + integratorKey + "\"}";
                Configuration.Default.AddDefaultHeader("X-DocuSign-Authentication", authHeader);
            }
        }

        private static string Authenticate()
        {
            var authApi = new AuthenticationApi();
            LoginInformation loginInfo = authApi.Login();

            //user might be a member of multiple accounts
            string accountId = loginInfo.LoginAccounts[0].AccountId;

            return accountId;
        }

        private static Document CreateDocusignDocument(ContractDocument document)
        {
            return new Document
            {
                DocumentBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(document.Document),
                Name = document.FormCode ?? "DocuSignContract.pdf",
                DocumentId = document.TrackingIdentity.ToString(),
                TransformPdfFields = "false"
            };
        }

        private EnvelopeDefinition CreateEnvelope(Document doc)
        {
            //Set envelope status to "sent" to instruct Docusign to immediately send the signature request upon receipt
            var envDef = new EnvelopeDefinition
            {
                EmailSubject = "[DocuSignContract] - Please eSign this doc",
                Documents = new List<Document> { doc },
                Status = "sent"
            };

            return envDef;
        }

        private static void AddSigners(EnvelopeDefinition envelope, List<ContractSigner> signers)
        {
            envelope.Recipients = new Recipients
            {
                Signers = new List<Signer>()
            };

            signers.ForEach(x => envelope.Recipients.Signers.Add(
                new Signer
                {
                    Name = x.FullName,
                    Email = x.Email,
                    RecipientId = ((int)x.Type).ToString(),
                    ClientUserId = x.UserId
                }
            ));
        }

        private string SendContractToDocusign(string accountId, EnvelopeDefinition envelope, List<ContractSigner> signers)
        {
            if (signers == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(signers));

            // Use the EnvelopesApi to create and send the signature request
            var envelopesApi = new EnvelopesApi();
            EnvelopeSummary envelopeSummary = envelopesApi.CreateEnvelope(accountId, envelope);

            return envelopeSummary.EnvelopeId;
        }

        public async Task<byte[]> GetSignedDocument(string envelopeId)
        {
            string accountId = Authenticate();

            var envelopesApi = new EnvelopesApi();
            var docList = await envelopesApi.ListDocumentsAsync(accountId, envelopeId);

            using (var docStream = (MemoryStream)envelopesApi.GetDocument(accountId, envelopeId, docList.EnvelopeDocuments[0].DocumentId))
            {
                return docStream.ToArray();
            }
        }

        public string SendContractToDocusign(ContractDocument contractData, List<ContractSigner> signers)
        {
            //Authenticate with Docusign and get account Id
            string accountId = Authenticate();

            //Create Docusign document from contract
            Document doc = CreateDocusignDocument(contractData);

            //Create an envelope and insert the document
            EnvelopeDefinition envelope = CreateEnvelope(doc);

            //Add signers
            AddSigners(envelope, signers);

            //Send the document to docusign
            var envelopeId = SendContractToDocusign(accountId, envelope, signers);

            return envelopeId;
        }


        public string GetSigningUrl(string envelopeId, ContractSigner signer, string returnUrl)
        {
            //Authenticate with Docusign and get account Id
            string accountId = Authenticate();

            var envelopesApi = new EnvelopesApi();

            var viewOptions = new RecipientViewRequest()
            {
                ReturnUrl = returnUrl,
                ClientUserId = signer.UserId,
                AuthenticationMethod = "Password",
                UserName = signer.FullName,
                Email = signer.Email
            };

            // create the recipient view (aka signing URL)
            ViewUrl recipientView = envelopesApi.CreateRecipientView(accountId, envelopeId, viewOptions);

            return recipientView.Url;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: can you post your create envelope call?

Comment: Added the code for the envelope call. My guess is that somehow when adding the signers I need to set a property of that signer to `SignatureBox1` which is the name of the signature box form field in the PDF. But I am not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are having PDF with the form fields and want that DocuSign should automatically convert your PDF form fields to DocuSign tabs then you need to created PDF with DS standard form field names. [PDF Transform Standards](https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/RESTAPIGuide.htm#REST%20API%20References/Document%20Parameters.htm#Transfor) will help you in knowing what should be your PDF form field name.

Also to convert PDF fields to DS Tabs automatically, you need to add `TransformPdfFields = true`, this tells DocuSign to convert the PDF Fields to DS Tabs.

or if you are not using above describer way, then you need to add the DS Tabs either using Anchor String or X/Y position. DS has recipes available at [Recipes](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/recipes)